# Does non-local interepretations of quantum mechanics imply FTL communication?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, faster-than-light, causality, time-travel, non-locality

For example the pilot wave theory... And if this is the case then does FTL commuincation imply time travel (i.e: information going back in time).

Answer (score 1):

"Interpretation" attributed to an alternate theory of physics, should be used only when , after calculating specific distributions to compare with measurement, the values are the same, so one cannot decide for one mathematical model versus the other.

So any new theory proposed as an interpretation cannot predict differently from the current quantum mechanical calculations, which of course have no  "faster than light", as special relativity is built in in Quantum field theory.

Now the [pilot wave theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_wave_theory) was developed for the non relativistic quantum mechanics, and there has been work trying to form a  special relativity version. I do not think they have managed to bring it to the "interpretation" level, i.e. give the same predictions as QFT.